# ValueError: (205087,) but got (1,), using fit_generator on onehot vectors in keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tf.keras

Alright so I am experimenting with keras as part of a project, and I get the following error that I just can't seem to resolve:
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (205087,) but got array with shape (1,)`
My code is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def iterdata():
    while(True):
        for d in data: #data is already defined in my script
            val=tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(d, num_classes=vocab_size) #this is the one_hot vector that causes troubles
            yield val, 0
word = Input(shape=(vocab_size,))
encode = Dense(1, activation=None)
encoded = shared_encode(word)

model = Model(inputs=word, outputs=encoded)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
H = model.fit_generator(iterdata(), 
        epochs=10,
        steps_per_epoch=10) #according to the Traceback, error happens while running this line
```

Running :

```
for d in iterdata():
    print(d[0].shape)
```

correctly prints `(205087,)`
So I do not know what to do with it, I did try yielding `np.asarray([val])` instead but still got the same error.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix.
In case that happens to you, you need to know that keras takes in inputs as batches, so your array needs to be one step deeper.
In my my case reshaping it to `(1,205807)` fixed the problem as it has nothing to do with the fact that it is generated nor any other reason, the format was just not as expected.

For example if your model accepts data like:
`[1,2,3]` you need to feed it `[[1,2,3]]`